# C# - Match Entity Property to String Value

Tags: c#, html

I am attempting to generate an HTML table where both column count and width can be customized.  I am also wanting to be able to bind specific columns from a table to their corresponding columns...

**Example Schema**:
[Invoice].[Quantity]
[Invoice].[ItemName]
[Invoice].[TotalAmount]

Originally, I was trying to mess with passing in an object with two properties (both Dictionaries).

Something like this:

```
public class CustomObject {
   public Dictionary<string, int> THTitle_Width { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, string> InvoiceColumn_CorrespondingTHTitle { get; set; }
}
```

My thought wanting to achieve something like:

```
THTitle_Width.Add("My Quantity Header", 100);
InvoiceColumn_CorrespondingTHTitle.Add("Quantity", "My Quantity Header");
```

Idea being that data within the [Invoice].[Quantity] column would then be known to fall under the table column "My Quantity Header" which in turn has a width of 100 (px).

This would then output:

```
<tr><th style="width:100px;">My Quantity Header</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
```

etc...

Reason being, you could just pass in this custom object and everything beyond that is handled.  Is this possible?  Maybe not in this way, but in another?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you doing this in ASP.NET or MVC?

Comment: This is actually going to be a console app that generates HTML then converted to a PDF.  All of the conversion functionality is present.  Just adding ability to easily customize (show/hide) columns and control column width.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using something like below: (Thanks to Stefan Hoffmann)

```
namespace Samples
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Text;

    public class Sample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            DataTable data = GetTable();
            HtmlTable html = new HtmlTable()
                .BindTable(data)
                .BindColumn("ID", "Ident", 64)
                .BindColumn("Name", "First name", 128)
                .BindColumn("Description", "Things to know", 256);
            Console.WriteLine(html.BuildHtml());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));            
            table.Rows.Add(1, "Alice", "Likes encryption.", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(2, "Bob", "Has to decrypt a lot.", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(3, "Charlie", "Not really funny.", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(4, "David", "Knows how to use stones.", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(5, "Elmer", "Don't mess with him, when wearing bunny ears.", DateTime.Now);
            return table;
        }
    }

    public class HtmlTable
    {
        private List<HtmlTableColumn> columns = new List<HtmlTableColumn>();
        private DataTable dataTable= null;

        public HtmlTable BindTable(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            this.dataTable = dataTable;
            return this;
        }

        public HtmlTable BindColumn(string columnName, string caption, int width)
        {
            this.columns.Add(new HtmlTableColumn() { Caption = caption, ColumnName = columnName, Width = width });
            return this;
        }

        public string BuildHtml()
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            // Build your HTML table.
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class HtmlTableColumn
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
    }
}
```